# "./gradlew bootRun --debug-jvm" is not working as it should be

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradlew

I am trying to debug the Spring Boot application with cmd "`./gradlew bootRun --debug-jvm`", earlier it was working fine but now when I am trying to build with cmd and trying to debug the code, my application is not going up. It is building without any error but still, application is not going up.

getting `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005` this message too.

IDK what happened , and i changed nothing in `build.gradle`, what can be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Debug can be turned on in different ways. Check the value of `GRADLE_OPTS` environment variable and `org.gradle.jvmargs` Java system property.

Latter can be set in different places: on the project level (in gradle.properties in project root) or in global config `~/.gradle/gradle.properties.`

Setting suspend to n will allow you to both run the process in debug mode and do not wait for the debugger.

More info can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-1828/gdabx/index.html#:%7E:text=Enable%20JVM%20Debugging&text=Click%20Java%20%3E%20JVM%20Settings%20tab,by%20clicking%20the%20New%20button.&text=If%20you%20substitute%20suspend%3Dy,a%20debugger%20attaches%20to%20it.)